# Call a javascript function automatically without buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I developed a javascript function that shows me the current time. Until then I had no problems. The problem is that I can not call this function in the place I want ... how can I call it using this?

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function showTime() {
  var timeNow = new Date();
  var hours   = timeNow.getHours();
  var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
  var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
  var timeString = "" + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
  timeString  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
  timeString  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
  timeString  += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
  document.htmlClock.timeField.value = timeString;
  timerID = setTimeout("showTime()", 1000);
}

</script>
```

Location where I want to call the function

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Hours here</a></li>
```

Comment: simply call the function after having declared it.. or use an interval or timeout outside the function like in jo_va's answer

Comment: Define `Automatically`. What do you mean by that? When the page loads or based on a frequency or when the user clicks on something or....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a `<span>` with an id where you want the time to be shown. Then query that `<span>` by id and set its `textContent`.
Use the `setInterval` function if you want to update the time at a regular interval:

```js
function getTime() {
  const timeNow = new Date();
  const hours   = timeNow.getHours();
  const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
  const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
  let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
  timeString  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
  timeString  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
  timeString  += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
  return timeString;
}

const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();

setInterval(() => {
  hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span id="hours"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks everyone for the answer !!

Answer (score 1):

You're suddenly calling the function `showTime`, and passing implicitly `undefined` to the function `setTimeout`.  In your approach you're actually passing a `String`, which will be evaluated (BAD).

*I recommend you to use the function `setInterval` for repeated calls of a function.*

Likewise, use the event `DOMContentLoaded` to be sure the HTML DOM tree is totally loaded before any DOM manipulation.

```js
function showTime() {
  var timeNow = new Date();
  var hours = timeNow.getHours();
  var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
  var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
  var timeString = "" + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
  timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
  timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
  timeString += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
  document.getElementById('hourshere').textContent = timeString;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  showTime();
  setInterval(showTime, 1000);
});
```

```html
Location where I want to call the function
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
<span id='hourshere'>Hours here</span>
</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function showTime() {
  var timeNow = new Date();
  var hours   = timeNow.getHours();
  var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
  var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
  var timeString = "" + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
  timeString  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
  timeString  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
  timeString  += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
  document.htmlClock.timeField.value = timeString;
  //timerID = setTimeout("showTime()", 1000); //No longer needed
}

</script>
```

So it would be:

```
var t=setInterval(showTime,1000);
```

And to stop it, you can run:

```
clearInterval(t);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><script>showTime()</script></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick="showTime()` to the html element you want when clicked, calls the function `showTime()` .

If you want to show the time after the link is clicked,

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="showTime()"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Hours here</a></li>
```

or if you want to show the time after the icon is clicked,

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" onclick="showTime()"></i>Hours here</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: Happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

On the javascript side maybe you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("clock").onclick = {
var timeNow = new Date();
var hours   = timeNow.getHours();
var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
var timeString = "" + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
timeString  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
timeString  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
timeString  += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
document.htmlClock.timeField.value = timeString;
timerID = setTimeout("showTime()", 1000);
};
```

Html

```
<li><a href="#"><i id="clock"></i>Hours here</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer and others are all great. My only suggestion is to modify your original code for the date. As I was looking at it, I noticed some parts could be left out.

Here's the JS from the accepted answer:

```
function getTime() {
  const timeNow = new Date();
  const hours   = timeNow.getHours();
  const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
  const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
  let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
  timeString  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
  timeString  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
  timeString  += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
  return timeString;
}

const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();

setInterval(() => {
  hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
}, 1000);
```

And here is what I suggest:

```
function getTime() {
  const timeNow = new Date();
  const hours   = timeNow.getHours();
  const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
  const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
  // use hours > 12 to generate 12-hour time because hours will never be greater than 24
  let timeString = '' + ((hours > **12**) ? hours - 12 : hours);
  timeString  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
  timeString  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
  timeString  += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
  return timeString;
}

const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
// can omit this line, since it is handled by the setInterval function
// hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();

setInterval(() => {
  hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
}, 1000);
```

The markup is unchanged:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span id="hours"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```